# How to edit AWS OpenSearch Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards, amazon-opensearch

to change the logo in AWS Opensearch need to edit the **opensearch_dashboards.yml** file. But where it is located in **OpenSearch Cluster**?

Went through the different resources and couldn't able to find a way to change the dashboard logo?

[image]

Comment: Is it a self managed cluster and do you have access to .yml file? If yes, you need to create one if you don't have it. More at https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/dashboards/branding/

Comment: @Riz i don't know much about OpenSearch , i created a domain and build the OpenSearch dashboard. I saw that doc but iim implementaed on AWS not locally or using Docker.

Comment: Then you can't have access to the nodes and you cannot modify the .yml file.

Comment: @Riz Is there way to access nodes? how can i modify .yml File? Where are actually nodes located?

Comment: this is AWS documentation. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/gsgcreate-domain.html so where cani i get access to nodes when creating a domain?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between user managed and aws managed. In your case it's aws managed so aws dones' t give you much controll and definitly access to .yml file. So in short, there is no way you can have access to the configuration file. You don't have access to the nodes/servers where opensearch will be running.

Comment: @Riz Thanks .By any chance do you know any workaround to change the dashboard logo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we cant change the OpenSearch dashboard logo since it's managed by AWS.